# ¿Como llenar un <select> en una plantilla .ejs con los datos de una tabla consultada al momento de cargar?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, axios, ejs

Requiero llenar un  en una plantilla ejs que me hace un redner en Javascript para mostar unas opciones que se deben cargar de una consulta a una base de datos MySQL, la tabla que devuelve la consutla contienes los tipos de créditos que maneja una empresa. ¿Cómo se puede hacer esto, llenar dicho  justo cuando se cargue la plantilla para mostrar al usuario?